# AndroidExtensionsGradleModel Unsupported major.minor version 52.0. Please use JDK 8 or newer

Tags: intellij-idea

I try to start intellij idea(2019.1.2) and get the following error:

```
org/jetbrains/kotlin/android/synthetic/idea/AndroidExtensionsGradleModel : 
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0. Please use JDK 8 or newer.
```

I use gradle to build project. Also I see that run build task was failed.

Gradle Version is 4.5. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208050, are you using JDK7?

Comment: @PetrRastegaev Yes, I am.